# How to hide some, but not all, subsections from table of contents, without losing in-document subsection numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using `\tableofcontents`. I'd like to hide some, but not all, subsections from the contents, but I don't want to lose the subsection numbering within the document itself. (So I can't use `\subsection*{}`.) Is there an easy way to do this? If not, could someone provide a clever solution?

In my case, if I want to suppress a single subsection within a section, then I want to suppress all the subsections in that section. I don't need the flexibility to both suppress and incorporate subsections within a single section.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{To be included in TOC}
\subsection{Also to be included in TOC}

\section{Another Section}
\subsection{Not to be included in TOC}

\section{Another Section Redux}
\subsection{Not to be included in TOC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer depends on the class and on already used packages, which are used to manipulate the section headings or the table of contents. So without a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) every answer would be speculative.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: okay, thanks; I'll add a MWE.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Hide details of a chapter from TOC and list of tables, figures and algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346068/5764). The suggestion there is to use a toggle `\hidefromtoc` to hide content from being written to the ToC, and `\writetotoc` to activate ToC-writing again.

Comment: @Werner: that did it; thanks very much. Should I delete the question?